# How to set an encrypted .json file inside Travis CI server?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, travis-ci

I'm using Google's Firebase on a Java project and I'm trying to get Travis CI working on my repository.

The problem is: How do I put the .json key to access the database in a enviroment variable inside Travis CI server?

I'm aware of how to set an enviroment variable in Travis CI, the thing is how to set a full .json file?

Comment: Maybe you don't? Instead, put the various values from the json file into individual variables, and then generate the json file as part of the CI process.

Comment: That could be a solution, I'm going to give it a try. A problem that already comes to my mind is that the Firestore's Java library searches for an specif enviroment variable called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.